# Have anybody compared ASP.NET MVC to CodeIgniter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, codeigniter

Is there a lot of similarities? I can webforms ASP.NET and some CodeIgniter but haven't much grokked with the asp.net mvc. Have they a lot of similarities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than being frameworks build around MVC there aren't many similarities.  (ie they both have folders for Models/Controllers/Views and automatically wire things for you based on naming conventions)

CodeIgniter is the most basic implementation of MVC possible, which allows for incredible flexibility when building your app.

ASP.NET MVC has alot built into it, and is strongly typed.  LINQ to SQL provides a built in ORM and the basic MVC templates have frameworks for authentication built in utilizing ASP.NET Membership provider model.

Views in MVC are typed as well, so you have to define the model being passed into the view as opposed to CI which you can pass anything basically.

The helper classes are completely different as well.

ASP.MVC is built upon ASP.NET so alot of things will seem similar with Webforms, but you need to understand MVC pattern.  Check out the NerdDinner tutorial for a fantastic introduction to ASP.MVC. (which is a Wrox book which they now make available for free online)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/